# Determine the kernel of $L: \mathbb{R^4 \to R^3}, \ L(x,y,z,t) = (x+2y+t, -2x-t,x+y+z-2t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

## **Determine the kernel of $L: \mathbb{R^4 \to R^3}, \ L(x,y,z,t) = (x+2y+t, -2x-t,x+y+z-2t)$**

I got this solution: $Ker(L) = (-2,1,-11,-4)$

### My steps:
$$\begin{cases} x+2y+t = 0 \\ -2x-t = 0 \\ x+y+z-2t=0 \end{cases}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ -2 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 3 & 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$$
(using [Gauss elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination))
$$\begin{cases} -x+2y = 0 \\ -2x-t = 0 \\ 3y+z-2t=0 \end{cases} \ \begin{cases} x=2y \\ t = -2x \\ z+3y+8y=0 \end{cases} \ \begin{cases} x=2y \\ t = -4y \\ z=-11y \end{cases}$$
$$Ker(L) = (-2y,y,-11y,-4y) = y (-2,1,-11,-4)$$

Is that correct? and there is a way to check if the solutions of these types of exercises are correct?

Comment: You do know, using Gaussian Elimination, that the row-space of the matrix has dimension 3. This means $L$ is a surjection. From the Rank-Nullity theorem, $\operatorname{dim(ker}L) = 1$. So you only have to find one solution. However, the vector you have shown is not a part of the kernel.

Comment: @Gauss so what is the kernel?

Comment: It seems like $\{(-2, 1, -7, -4)k \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid k \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Answer (score 1):

Wrong use of Gauss elimination. With the matrix you obtained the last equation of your system is rather $3y+z-2t=0$. Remark that the gauss eliminations is completed when you reduce your matrix to row-echelon form,so in fact you performed only some kind of partial elimination.

Comment: You're right! it was a typo, I just fixed it, thanks, by the way, I know that I've not completed the Gauss elimination, however, I did not know how to continue from where I had arrived, so I proceeded by using substitution.